# Is there any solution to do per process based traffic shaping in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, traffic

is there any solution to use per process basis?

I mean when I do HTTP download, I can't browse web. It's no use to prioritize traffic based on protocol in this case. So, what I need is to give firefox process high priority and wget process to low priority. So I can brows web and use HTTP downloads too.

In windows it's possible by using cfosspeed software. So, in Linux, it should be possible, because in Linux everything can be done. Please somebody help me..

Comment: Why not use a download manager and limit the speed there? There are several available working with Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a download manager to limit the download rate of your files, several are available for the most popular browsers.

If you want to use `wget` for that, the option **--limit-rate=amount** can be used out of the box for that purpose.

No need to do traffic shaping of sorts when the tools you use allow you to do so. No?

Comment: It leads to waste of time. I have 2Mbps connection. So I get download speeds like 200KB/s. So, the problem is I don't always load web pages. I load some page and read things in it. So, browser only need about 20seconds to load webpage. So, limiting rate will always limit the rate. It's no a solution. What I need is, when browser process want to use network, system should give that process higher priority. So, wget download rate will decrease for only that time. Once browser process's traffic went, wget will download at peak level.

Answer (score 0):

## Wondershaper

You might want to try Wondershaper (although it seems that it will prioritize http traffic over torrents and might therefore not work).

See [this page](http://howifixed.it/shape-bandwidth-with-wondershaper-for-debian-based-systems/) on how to install and use it - and to get more info about it.

Comment: I know about wondershaper. As far as I know, it can't use to shape traffic per process basis. It only shape by protocol basis. (which I can do using tc command too)

Comment: I don't know anything other than Wondershaper, but a quick search on alternativeto.net shows [L7-filter](http://l7-filter.clearfoundation.com") as the only Linux alternative.